# how to add events to calendar with google calendar api

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, datetime-format, voice-recognition

for example; I have a meeting at 2 o'clock on December 8th, I'm trying to make a python voice assistant that will add the appropriate date in the calendar as an event when I give the voice command, but it creates an event at the current time and date by adding the command I gave as an event to the calendar title, how can I fix this?

```
def parse_command(command):

  date=datetime.now()
  summary = ""

  parts = command.split(" ")
  for i in range(len(parts)):
      if parts[i] == "saat" and i+1 < len(parts):
          time = parts[i+1]
      elif parts[i] == "tarihinde" and i+1 < len(parts):
          try:
              date = datetime.strptime(parts[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
          except ValueError:
              print("Geçersiz tarih formatı. Lütfen gün/ay/yıl formatında girin.")
              pass
      elif parts[i] != "toplantı":
          summary += parts[i] + " "

  if date is None or time is None:
      return "Tarih veya saat belirtilmedi", None, None

  # Zamanı oluştururken, başlangıç ve bitiş zamanları aynı formatta ve tipinde olmalı
  start_time = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") + "+00:00"
  end_time = (date + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") + "+00:00"

  return summary.strip(), start_time, end_time
```

Comment: Well you are telling it to create it at the current date and time arnt you date=datetime.now() Whats the issue?   can i get an example of command?

Comment: No, I got an error when I created the date variable as None, so I wanted it to use the current time by default this way, but replace it with the given  command I gave. but it doesn't change it. For example, when I say "8 Aralık'ta saat 2'de bir toplantım var", I want its to create an event on that date. @LindaLawton-DaImTo